# Populate form without runat="server"?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

For reasons I don't wish to get into, nor can I change, I am using .net web forms and was supplied with html that contained multiple forms.  You may only have a single form tagged runat="server" with web forms so I've had to take an unorthodox approach.

I am fine submitting a form by using HttpContext.Current.Request, however I am not how to go about populating form data.

The only idea I have is to create an ajax call on document.ready() which calls a static webMethod "on_load" which would return JSON.  This JSON is then parsed by a jquery function and populates the form with data.

I can't help but feel there is a better way to do this incorporating server side code, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not use `Request.Form[]`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request and Request are the same object.  This works for a form submit, however I am trying to populate data on a form load.For instance I get the name "John Doe" from the database and I try to fill a "full name" text box on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using plain HTML form elements (since you can't use `runat="server"` on your form element), you can set the value of the HTML elements directly in your aspx page.

Assume you have loaded your object, you can expose it via a public property in your aspx.cs code behind:

```
Public Property Person MyPerson { get; set; }
```

Then in your aspx code you could put the following:

```
<input type='text' value='<%=MyPerson.FirstName %>' />
```

Comment: If you don't have an object, you could expose each string value `Public string fullname { get; set;}` or `public string fullname = 'Prescott'`, if you have a ton of values to fill in, this will add a lot in your codebehind and is not as clean imo